# how to display dictionary keys as sections and values as rows in a table view in ios?

Tags: ios7

I have a NSMutableDictionary as  below,

```
NSMutableDictionary *aSite;
NSArray *aDocs=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaaa",@"bbbb",@"cccc", nil];
NSArray *bDocs=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaaa",@"bbbb",@"cccc", nil];
NSArray *cDocs=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaaa",@"bbbb",@"cccc", nil];
aSite=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[aSite setObject:aDocs forKey:@"A library"];
[aSite setObject:bDocs forKey:@"B library"];
[aSite setObject:cDocs forKey:@"C library"];
```

Now,I have to display the keys as section and values as rows in the section,how to do that? please help

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.Let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UITableViewDataSource implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return aSite.allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *arrayKey = [aSite.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *a = [aSite objectForKey:arrayKey];

    return a.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSString *arrayKey = [aSite.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *a = [aSite objectForKey:arrayKey];
    cell.textLabel.text = [a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Notice however that `allKeys` and `allValues` do not define a specific order (from the docs, "The order of the elements in the array is not defined"). I would convert your structure to an array of arrays before loading the data in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

You will get all the keys in NSArray like:

```
NSArray*sectionArray =[aSite allKeys];
```

After this use table use table view datasource method to set the header and table rows :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return sectionArray.count;
}
```

and

```
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

in those method you have to load the cell conditionally .

Answer (score 0):

Grab your "dictionary of arrays", and:

1. Take all the `values`, and assemble an array of arrays. Each array represents all the rows for one section of the table view.
2. Take all the `keys`, and assemble them into an array of `NSString`s. Use this as the section names for the table view.